# Logic element to CNF

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have a big problem with a XNOR element expression. I analyzed the circuit in LOGISIM and it wrote me the minimal type of CNF which is (A + B + D)*(A + B + ~C)*(~B + C + ~D)*(~A + C + ~D). 
The base XNOR expression looks like this  Y = ~(A + B) XNOR ~(C+~D)
The minimal DNF type of this XNOR expression is this (~A ~B ~C*D + B*~D + B*C + A* ~D + A*C)
We sat on this for 3 whole days and can't treat this expression to that final CNF form. Could be so kind and make a little attention to this expression?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well I need the steps how to get from the basic expression to this minimal CNF.